# How Can I Start From Exactly Where I Left Off Using HTML Local Storage?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am new in Javascript and I have started to convert a large pdf book into webpage using HTML, CSS and Javascript.

As this book is pretty large, I want to make my app start from where I left off so that I don't forget till which part I have read so far.

I know it can be done by getting scroll height using Javascript scrollTop() function and putting it in HTML Web Storage, and finally I have to restore that position via a call to scrollTo() function.
I tried, but my code isn't working as expected.
What should I do now?

I am showing you actual HTML/JS Code. Please have a look and tell me where am I making mistakes.

---

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>T-Rex Album|Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">


<script>

function herok(){
    var a=localStorage.setItem("LastPosition", "CurrentPosition");
    var elmnt=document.getElementById("myDIV");
    var CurrentPosition=elmnt.scrollTop;


    localStorage.setItem("LastPosition", "CurrentPosition");
    var FinalPosition=document.getElementById('cat').innerHTML=localStorage.getItem("LastPosition");

}


function scrollWin() {
    window.scrollTo(0, a);
}
</script>



  </head>
<body onunload="herok()">
        <button onclick="scrollWin()" style="position:fixed;">Start From Where You Left</button>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    <p>dummy text</p>
    
 
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you  want save the value don't use double quotes  but var name

```
var CurrentPosition=elmnt.scrollTop;

localStorage.setItem("LastPosition", CurrentPosition);
```

Comment: have checked i bwoser  console you have error? .. and  can you tell me  how you can check the correct result if your  herok() function  is called  when onunload succed .. ?